# How to use both vue-router and vuex correctly in a vite-vue SSR app?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router, server-side-rendering, vite

I'm learning Vue **SSR**. I tried to rewrite one of my project and use [**Server-Side Rendering**](https://vitejs.dev/guide/ssr.html#server-side-rendering) that is suggested by **Vite** documentation. In that page there is a link to [this repo](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/tree/main/playground/ssr-vue) as a starter template for Vue 3 SSR. I used that and now I want to use **Vuex** in my project. I want to have a separate file (for example **store.js**) similar to `router.js` that is responsible for my vuex. Unfortunately in that repo there **is not** such a file. So I searched in web and found [this guide](https://vite-plugin-ssr.com/vuex#example) and [this repo](https://github.com/brillout/vite-plugin-ssr/tree/main/examples/vuex) that are similar but not exact match to my first repository. Because I'm new in this topic and the syntax and maybe plugins that were used in that two repo are different, I'm a bit confused that **How to use both Vuex and Vue-router correctly?** in my SSR app.

What I understood is that if we accept the [first repo](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/tree/main/playground/ssr-vue) as a base to add Vuex, we need to change at least 4 files: `main.js`, `entry-server.js`, `entry-client.js` and added `store.js`.

Below is that four file in my project:

> main.js:

```js
import { createSSRApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import { createRouter } from './router'
import { createStore } from './store'

// SSR requires a fresh app instance per request, therefore we export a function
// that creates a fresh app instance. If using Vuex, we'd also be creating a
// fresh store here.
export function createApp() {
  const app = createSSRApp(App)
  const router = createRouter()
  const store = createStore()
  
  app.use(router)
  app.use(store)
  
  return { app, router, store }
}
```

> entry-client.js:

```js
import { createApp } from './main'

const { app, router } = createApp();

// wait until router is ready before mounting to ensure hydration match
router.isReady().then(() => {
  app.mount('#app')
})
```

> entry-server.js:

```js
import { basename } from 'node:path'
import { renderToString } from 'vue/server-renderer'
import { createApp } from './main'

export async function render(url, manifest) {
  const { app, router } = createApp()

  // set the router to the desired URL before rendering
  await router.push(url)
  await router.isReady()

  // passing SSR context object which will be available via useSSRContext()
  // @vitejs/plugin-vue injects code into a component's setup() that registers
  // itself on ctx.modules. After the render, ctx.modules would contain all the
  // components that have been instantiated during this render call.
  const ctx = {}
  const html = await renderToString(app, ctx)

  // the SSR manifest generated by Vite contains module -> chunk/asset mapping
  // which we can then use to determine what files need to be preloaded for this
  // request.
  const preloadLinks = renderPreloadLinks(ctx.modules, manifest)
  return [html, preloadLinks]
}

function renderPreloadLinks(modules, manifest) {
  let links = ''
  const seen = new Set()
  modules.forEach((id) => {
    const files = manifest[id]
    if (files) {
      files.forEach((file) => {
        if (!seen.has(file)) {
          seen.add(file)
          const filename = basename(file)
          if (manifest[filename]) {
            for (const depFile of manifest[filename]) {
              links += renderPreloadLink(depFile)
              seen.add(depFile)
            }
          }
          links += renderPreloadLink(file)
        }
      })
    }
  })
  return links
}

function renderPreloadLink(file) {
  if (file.endsWith('.js')) {
    return `<link rel="modulepreload" crossorigin href="${file}">`
  } else if (file.endsWith('.css')) {
    return `<link rel="stylesheet" href="${file}">`
  } else if (file.endsWith('.woff')) {
    return ` <link rel="preload" href="${file}" as="font" type="font/woff" crossorigin>`
  } else if (file.endsWith('.woff2')) {
    return ` <link rel="preload" href="${file}" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin>`
  } else if (file.endsWith('.gif')) {
    return ` <link rel="preload" href="${file}" as="image" type="image/gif">`
  } else if (file.endsWith('.jpg') || file.endsWith('.jpeg')) {
    return ` <link rel="preload" href="${file}" as="image" type="image/jpeg">`
  } else if (file.endsWith('.png')) {
    return ` <link rel="preload" href="${file}" as="image" type="image/png">`
  } else {
    // TODO
    return ''
  }
}
```

> store.js:

```js
import Vuex from 'vuex'

export { createStore }

function createStore() {
  const store = Vuex.createStore({
    state() {
      return {
        todoList: []
      }
    },

    actions: {
      fetchTodoList({ commit }) {
        const todoList = [
          {
            id: 0,
            text: 'Buy milk'
          },
          {
            id: 1,
            text: 'Buy chocolate'
          }
        ]
        return commit('setTodoList', todoList)
      }
    },

    mutations: {
      setTodoList(state, todoList) {
        state.todoList = todoList
      }
    }
  })

  return store
}
```

They are some combinations of that two repo codes. But probably needs to have some changes to work perfectly. I'm not sure that if any other files is necessary to add or change. I’m so grateful for the help of a developer that have more experience in this topic to correct my files to use both **Vuex** and **Vue-router**.

Comment: Hi, why have you deleted this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74582402/how-to-use-markdown-it-footnote-with-nuxt-js

Comment: @kissu, Hi, thanks for your "perseverance" and "attention" in my question! After some hours when I posted that question, I restart the local server, I'm not sure that is the reason or not, but I noticed that the app was working correctly after some hours. So I deleted the post!